# FlyWay: Why are schemas not created when setInitOnMigrate is set?

Tags: flyway

Scenario:

- Existing database with one schema, the `transport` schema.
- 2 migration files where version 1 is the initial / base version. Version 2 adds a table to the `management` schema (but does not create that schema, I want FlyWay to do that).

Using FlyWay API (in Java application)

```
//...
flyway.setSchemas("transport", "management");
flyway.setInitVersion("1");
flyway.setInitOnMigrate(true);
flyway.migrate();
```

migration version 2 fails because the `management` schema has not being created. This succeeds as expected on a clean database.

I get the same problem when executing migrations via the maven plugin.

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <schemas>
        <schema>transport</schema>
        <schema>management</schema>
    </schemas>
</configuration>

...

mvn flyway:init -Dflyway.initVersion=1 -Dflyway.initDescription="Base version"
mvn flyway:migrate
```

Seems like if you are using FlyWay with an existing database, you then lose the ability to have FlyWay manage additional schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported. At this point it is an all or nothing deal. Please file a feature request in the issue tracker.