# Flyway: non-empty schema without metadata table

Tags: flyway

`Found non-empty schema "public" without metadata table! Use init() or set initOnMigrate to true to initialize the metadata table.`

- I'm using Postgres 9.2 with Postgis 2.0. This means that by default when I create a new database there will be a table created in `public` schema called `spatial_ref_sys`.

When I run `flyway migrate` on this database, I get the above error. Running `init` seems to create the `public.schema_version` table and mark version 1 as SUCCEDED without actually running the the migration file. I've also tried combinations of `initOnMigrate` with no success. Flyway is not configured to manage any schemas.

Any ideas on how I can run a migration in this scenario?

Comment: I've altered the title of the question even further to simply state the error message. The original title "Migrate a virgin database causes errors" was simply incorrect as stated in the comments below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The title is somewhat contradictory, as the database is indeed not virgin as you installed, through the PostGIS extension, a number of objects in the public schema.

You can either

- set `flyway.schemas` to a new schema, say my_app, which will then be created automatically by Flyway. Your application should then use this one instead of public (recommended)
- set `flyway.baselineOnMigrate` to `true` or invoke `flyway.baseline()` against the public schema. This will work, but public will then contain a mix of both your application objects and the PostGIS objects

Comment: Fair point, altered the title and content to reflect the caveat. Thanks for the answers again Axel, will hit it again on Monday and come back with my results.

Comment: As an aside, if you have any comments on [this Flyway / EJB integration question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557898/bootstrap-ejb3-application-before-jpa-hibernate-startup), I'd love to hear any of your comments.

Comment: What I have done is added `flyway` to `flyway.schemas` so `schema_version` is completely isolated. We have ~7 schemas at the moment, so in [reference to your answer on my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374196/flyway-why-are-schemas-not-created-when-setinitonmigrate-is-set) I am going with the "nothing" approach. With this setup, migrating a virgin* database works. On an existing database however, `init -initVersion=2` will work as desired but `migrate -initOnMigrate=true -initVersion=2` will try to run all migrations. This seems contradictory to the documentation.

Comment: I've added an [issue on github](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/842) regarding `initOnMigrate` and also contributed a work in progress patch in the comments section for further discussion.

Comment: Using JPA, you can tell your entities about the new schema by the "schema" property. e.g. @Table(name = "posts", schema = "blog").

Comment: `flyway.initOnMigrate` is deprecated from Flyway 3.1 (2014-11-27), use `flyway.baselineOnMigrate` instead

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Gradle you can run

```
./gradlew -Dflyway.schemas=public flywayClean flywayMigrate
```

Where public is the name of the database containing the schema_versions table.  That should delete the table and metadata as well as running the migrations to get it back up to date.

### Caution!

This will delete all data in `public` schema

Answer (score 2):

I think this error comes only with latest version of Flyway i.e. above 4.03. I didn't received in the earlier project but got it when I am using Flyway version 5.07 in my latest project. Putting the code here that resolve my issues

```
public class FlywayConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    Config config;

    @Bean
    public Flyway flyway(){
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
         flyway.setSqlMigrationPrefix("V");
            flyway.setLocations(new String[] { config.getSqlLocation() });
            flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
            // *******************flyway.clean(); ********************// this will wipe out the DB, be careful
            flyway.migrate();
        return  flyway;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me , i were figthin with the same problema a lot of time

my project was building on maven

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
flyway.setLocations("db/your_db");
flyway.setTable("name_of_schema");
```

next a added this line

```
flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
flyway.clean();
```

next this lines

```
 MigrationInfo migrationInfo = flyway.info().current();
 flyway.migrate();
```

and i let you the URL of my references from flyway.org
[Flyway.org/documentation/commandline/baseline](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/baseline)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem started when I deleted all the rows in the table myschema.schema_version

`./gradlew flywayInit` did the trick and the error is not showed anymore.